# How can I deploy a WordPress site with Git without committing WP core?

Tags: git, wordpress, deployment, automation, updates

I've been researching how to use git for WordPress deployment. Nearly all of the examples have WordPress as a remote repository that is merged into master/feature branch regularly.

I don't want to commit the WordPress core into my repository. I basically want to ignore everything except the files I'll be changing (mainly my custom theme). Is there a simple way I can do this, but still keep a local, staging and production server running the same WordPress version?

Comment: You do know that when you commit with got only changes are pushed or pulled? or I guess I'm missing the point

Comment: Use your `.gitignore` file. [Example](https://gist.github.com/jdbartlett/444295)

Answer (score 1):

Merging the remote repository isn't necessary unless you want changes from upstream in your copy.

Suppose you have your Wordpress locally in a folder called `wp` and it isn't already a git repo:

```
cd wp
git init .
touch .gitignore # Add required stuff to .gitignore.
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit."
```

Now when you want to reflect these changes remotely just push to the remote of your production or staging servers.

```
git push staging master
```

### Possible Solution via git Submodules

Say you have your Wordpress setup on github. First clone the repo:

```
git clone git://github.com/Soliah/Wordpress.git
cd Wordpress
git checkout origin/3.2-branch
```

Now say you have a theme "awesomeness":

```
cd Wordpress
git submodule add https://github.com/Soliah/awesomeness.git ./wp-content/themes/awesomeness
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Now anytime you want to update your theme first update the theme repo:

```
cd awesomeness
# update some stuff
git add .
git commit -m "Update theme."
git push origin master
```

Back in wordpress just update the submodule and push to github.

```
cd Wordpress
git submodule update
git commit -m "Update theme submodules."
git push origin master
```

On your other servers you can either `git clone git://github.com/Soliah/Wordpress.git && git submodule update --init` or `git pull` if they're already present.

Comment: That would either commit the WordPress core into my repository, or ignore it entirely which means I'm back to manually maintaining the WP version across local, staging and production.

Comment: If you could provide more info of how you've got your repos setup it might help. But thinking about it now git submodules might be what you want.

Comment: I added a possible solution via submodules.